# #define _GNU_SOURCE in Cygwin?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, cygwin, affinity

I tried using -D_GNU_SOURCE when compiling but neither works, I am trying to use pthread_setaffinity_np and other mutithreading features but the compiler says it is out of scope. This is what I have:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
int cpuAff(){ //set processor affinity
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(0, &cpuset);
    pthread_setaffinity_np(threads[0], sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
    pthread_setaffinity_np(threads[1], sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
    pthread_setaffinity_np(threads[2], sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
    pthread_setaffinity_np(threads[3], sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
}
```

I am using cygwin on windows 10 if that is the problem? any body know a fix?

Comment: Nothing of this is present in the cygwin header tree.

Comment: Is there a way for me yo use these functions in cygwin?

Comment: Same problem for me @Y.Yami

Comment: This is answered in this SO question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771345/cpu-set-t-does-not-name-a-type-c