# 'cpu_set_t' does not name a type C++

Tags: c++, g++, scheduler, cpuset

I'm working on building a rate monotonic scheduler for an assignment and I need to get all my threads to run on the same processor.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I keep getting the same error (see pic below).  I've been looking through a bunch of Linux documentation to try and figure out what to do but I just can't.  I would really appreciate some help.  Thanks in advance.

[image: Error]
My Scheduler.cpp file:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

sem_t semaphore;
sem_t mutex1;
sem_t mutex2;
sem_t mutex3;
sem_t mutex4;

// initialze variables
int i = 0;
int overrun1 = 0;
int overrun2 = 0;
int overrun3 = 0;
int overrun4 = 0;

int doWork();
void* p1(void *param);
void* p2(void *param);
void* p3(void *param);
void* p4(void *param);



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
cpu_set_t cpus;

CPU_ZERO(&cpus);
CPU_SET(1, &cpus);

sem_init(&mutex1, 0, 0);
sem_init(&mutex2, 0, 0);
sem_init(&mutex3, 0, 0);
sem_init(&mutex4, 0, 0);

// initialze all threads
pthread_t thread1;
pthread_t thread2;
pthread_t thread3;
pthread_t thread4;

// actually create all threads
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, p1, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, p2, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, p3, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread4, NULL, p4, NULL);

while (i < 160)
{
    if (i == 0) // initial case.  at time 0 schedule all threads
    {
        sem_post(&mutex1);
        sem_post(&mutex2);
        sem_post(&mutex3);
        sem_post(&mutex4);
    }

    else if (i % 16 == 0) // last case which happens every 16 units which schedules all threads again
    {
        sem_post(&mutex1);
        sem_post(&mutex2);
        sem_post(&mutex3);
        sem_post(&mutex4);
    }

    else if (i % 4 == 0) // case that happens every 4 units of time
    {
        sem_post(&mutex1);
        sem_post(&mutex2);
        sem_post(&mutex3);
    }

    else if (i % 2 == 0) // case that happens every other unit of time
    {
        sem_post(&mutex1);
        sem_post(&mutex2);
    }

    else if (i % 1 == 0) // case that happens every unit of time
    {
        sem_post(&mutex1);
    }
    i++; // increment i to go through the loop again
}

// join all threads back to the main one
pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
pthread_join(thread3, NULL);
pthread_join(thread4, NULL);

return 0;
}

// doWork function

int doWork()
{
int lousyArray[10][10];
int product = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        lousyArray[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            product *= lousyArray[i][j];
        }
    }
}
return 1;
}


void* p1(void *param)
{
    bool thread1FinishFlag = false;
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex1);
        thread1FinishFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            doWork();
        }
        //increment counter here
        thread1FinishFlag = true;
    }
}
void* p2(void *param)
{
    bool thread2FinishFlag = false;
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex2);
        thread2FinishFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            doWork();
        }
        //increment counter here
        thread2FinishFlag = true;
    }
}
void* p3(void *param)
{
    bool thread3FinishFlag = false;
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex3);
        thread3FinishFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            doWork();
        }
        //increment counter here
        thread3FinishFlag = true;
    }
}
void* p4(void *param)
{
    bool thread4FinishFlag = false;
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex4);
        thread4FinishFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            doWork();
        }
        //increment counter here
        thread4FinishFlag = true;
    }
}

void nsleep()
{
    struct timespec delay;

    delay.tv_sec = 0;
    delay.tv_sec = 100000000L;
    nanosleep(&delay, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You're apparently missing the `#include` file that declares `cpu_set_t` and the `CPU_ZERO` and `CPU_SET` macros.

Comment: @BaummitAugen He posted his entire source file. What more is needed for the MCVE?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing wrong. According to the man page, you need `#define _GNU_SOURCE` and `#include <sched.h>`, and you have both of these.

Comment: @Barmar Not sure if you are joking, but anyways: Posting the entire source file that contains some error is hardly *minimal*.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error on my system.

Comment: @BaummitAugen As I'm sure you understand, posters don't always know which parts are important, so it's hard for them to minimize to just that part. The more serious problem is when the code they post isn't complete or verifiable, he didn't make that mistake.

Comment: @Barmar In this case, we are talking about a compilation error. The compiler points to the exact line that's problematic. The effort to make something a lot more minimal than "just dump all the code" can and has to be expected from askers, even if it's "hard".

Comment: @BaummitAugen Come on, you know it's not that simple. There can be all sorts of dependencies on lines that aren't mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To everyone who replied to this post: I thank you for the quick response.  First and foremost I probably should have mentioned that I'm using Cygwin for Windows to compile this program.  Secondly, I apologize for not making the post shorter.  Finally, I found out after asking a colleague that Cygwin itself doesn't have support for setting processor affinity within code itself.

Thank you